# Best practice for natural keys in a dimension that includes data from multiple source table

Tags: data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling, star-schema

I am designing a dimension for a data warehouse that includes several related attributes from various tables.  When loading the fact tables I generally like to look up the surrogate keys from the dimension tables based on keys from from the source system rather than text matching on various attributes.  For a situation like the one I'm facing is it preferable to have several source system key columns in the dimension table (one from each of the relevant tables) to do the lookup on, or to create a single lookup column by using some sort of hash or concatenation?

Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Can you give an example?  I'm needing some clarification on "several source key columns".

Comment: Nick: In this case the dimension stores data about tumors, specifically it stores the tumor site, tumor lineage, and a tumor sub lineage.  Each of those data points come from a different table, but they are related in such a way that they belong in the same dimension.  So for example there is a tumorSiteId from the tumor site table, a lneageId from the lineage table and a subLineageId from the subLineage table.  Does that help?

Comment: @wshato I would recommend to create reproducible example: a create table sql script(s), and 2+ csv source data examples. Having such a question you can more easily get a precise answer.

Answer (score 2):

The best practice is a column that amounts to 'source system' and one (or more) columns of a unified type to accommodate the native keys of those source systems (probably with a bit of head room for future proofing).

A hash or concatenation to identify source should always be seen as a workaround when you can't control the data model.

A 'Source' column helps with lineage.

So suppose you have three source systems with varying 'Product Code' formats that are all char 8 , 10 and 15 respectively.
Add columns:

```
SourceID CHAR(5) - e.g. or a further surrogate look-up to a 'Source' table.
ProductCode CHAR(15)
```

15 = MAX(8,10,15).

Or even `VCHAR(20)` depending on whether you can expect future acquisition of sources. 20 Characters is pretty large for any source identifier. But do consider practices in the relevant problem domain.

Never

```
SourceID CHAR(5)
ProductCode1 CHAR(8)
ProductCode2 CHAR(10)
ProductCode3 CHAR(15)
```

If only because if Source 4 shows up you're adding columns.
Also because no report will usefully be displayed like that.
It will be hard to join to any generic 'common' tables you might have to deal with.
You may find you waste storage and bloat indexes with the wasted space of impair performance by opting for `VCHAR`.